AVR instructions LDS and STS 16 bit versions with GNU assembler
the AVR 8bit core instruction set includes the more efficient 16bit versions of the "load data from memory" (LDS) and "store data to memory" (STS) instructions, as opposed to the 32bit versions. As per the AVR Instruction Set Manual, the assembler syntax for the two versions is exactly identical. Obviously the assembler is meant to find out by itself if the 16bit version can be used (i.e. the address is 7bit only, and the register is one of R16:31). Only I find the GNU assembler does not. It always emits the 32bit version.
As an example, consider the assembler code
    lds   r17, 0x4D
The GNU assembler emits
  c4:    10 91 4d 00     lds r17, 0x004D
where it should have emitted
  c4:    1D A4           lds r17, 0x4D
Maybe it is necessary to explicitly tell the assembler to use the 16bit version, perhaps by using a different mnemonic (deviating from the instruction Set manual)?
How can I make the GNU assmbler (AVR version) emit the 16bit versions of the LDS and STS instructions?
Update: The instructions are part of inline assembly in C code, hence the assembler is not directly used but called from the C compiler. The controller is a ATmega32M1, which has an AVR5 core.

Did you select the correct MCU type? Which one is it?

I updated the question with the information.

The 16-bit LDS and STS are only available on the Reduced Tiny core, which is for devices ATtiny4, 5, 9, 10, 20, 40, 102 and 104, see -mmcu=avrtiny in the avr-gcc online documentation.
The addresses may be in the range 0x40...0xbf

LDS encodes as 1010 0kkk dddd kkkk
STS encodes as 1010 1kkk dddd kkkk

where d encodes the register R16...R31, and k encodes the address.

Then there are the avr1 devices ATtiny11, 12, 15, 28, AT90S1200 that don't have RAM at all, and that have to use general purpose registers for static storage.

On all other cores, LDS and STS are 32-bit instructions that have an address range of 64 KiB from 0x0 to 0xffff.

LDS is encoded as 1001 000d dddd 0000
STS is encoded as 1001 001d dddd 0000

where d specifies the register R0...R31. The code is followed by a 16-bit address.

Then there are the devices with EBI (external bus interface) avrxmega5, avrxmega7 (ATxmega64A1, 64A1U, 128A1, 128A1U, 128A4U) that allow to connect external RAM that exceeds the 16-bit address space.  This was "solved" by new RAMP special function registers that extend the address at the high end: RAMPZ extends Z, RAMPD extends LDS and STS, etc. This is a pain and not supported by the compiler.  The only support from GCC is that it saves / restores these SFRs in ISR prologue / epilogue when they may be used in the ISR.


How can I make the GNU assmbler (AVR version) emit the 16bit versions of the LDS and STS instructions?

You can't, see above.

The instructions are part of inline assembly in C code

Notice, that on Reduced Tiny, you have to make sure that the address of a variable in static storage fits the LDS / STS address range. Notice for example that an ATtiny40 has RAM outside the 0x40...0xbf range. You can assert that a variable location fits that range by means of the absdata variable attribute
As you are using ATmega32M1, no restrictions apply to the address range.
For locations in the I/O range, the in and out instructions can be used. On non-Xmega, non-ReducedTiny devices, this range extends from 0x20...0x5f.  Notice you have to use inline asm print modifier %i to get a suitable I/O address. In the lower half of that range, instructions sbic, sbis, sbi and cbi can be used, too.
For examples on how to use addresses in inline asm, see the AVR-LibC inline asm Cookbook.

I have used inline assembly on AVR a fair bit, so I thought I was familiar with where to find information. But this "The 16-bit LDS and STS are only available on the Reduced Tiny core" does not appear anywhere I know. Definitely the gnu cc documentation to linked to does not have it. Where have you got it from? Compare my comments on the other answer above.

I know it from Binutils sources, ./include/opcode/avr.h. The constraints are explained in the comments above (they have nothing to do with inline asm constraints).

You probably have not selected the appropriate MCU model. Using for example -mavrtiny or -mall-opcodes the 16 bit encoding is emitted. Note that the value is 1D A1 not 1D A4 as you claimed.
1 0000 1DA1         lds r17, 0x4D


So you're saying the AVR5 core may not have the 16bit instructions version? The Instruction Set Manual lists limited availability for quite a few instructions, but the list is empty for the LDS / STS (16bit).

The MCU's datasheet has a chapter "Instruction Set Summary" which lists the LDS instruction, but according to the Instruction Set Manual both versions are called LDS, so this is inconclusive.

I also do not understand your other comment. According to the Instruction Set Manual, the byte "Ax" has x meaning the upper nibble of the address, which is 4, not 1.

Note that the bit order of the Ax is mixed up. Indeed the MCU datasheet does not specifically mention the 16 bit LDS but it does mention LDD Rd,Y+q which uses a conflicting encoding so if that is supported then the short LDS can not be. 1D A1 decodes as LDD R17, Y+37

Additionally the number of cycles are given as 2 which further confirms that is the 32 bit version.

Indeed, you figured it out. Gosh, I'm tired of Atmels and Microchip's buggy and incomplete documentation, I've stumbled too often. Do you know of a document that also specifies bit orders in commands?

Also, do you want to amend your answer above so that I can mark it as the solution? These comments disappear after a while. Seems I could amend it too, if you prefer.

Well, the question was how to get GNU assembler to emit the 16 bit version and I think I answered that. The question was not whether the ATmega32M1 supports it or not, or how it is encoded. As for the manual, this one shows the encoding.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
